# Can’t change types of items in info.plist, Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 5.1 I tried to add some new fields, but couldn’t change their types. With key and value everything is ok.
Here is some screenshots(this is MyApp-Info.plist):
[image: Clicking on type do nothing]

[image: same thing in control-click menu]

Is it a bug, or I’m doing something wrong? Other .plist files are ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to add, key, value and value type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ***not*** a bug. Certain Values In `Info.Plist` are required by iOS to be a certain type and simply can't be changed, thats why your other plists work.

Comment: So, apple says to use CFBundleURLTypes for creating an array of dictionaries of URL Schemes. What should I choose from list?

Comment: They should be strings, see the following link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102207

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the property list's type in order to fully modify it through Xcode. The `info.plist` type locks certain keys, and you can get around this by changing the list's type to `None`. Although, it is worth saying that some of these value's types aren't meant to be modified.

[image]